# Get string name of function piped into another function

Tags: r, function, pipe, magrittr, non-standard-evaluation

While passing in a function into another function, I want the string name of this function. I also want this to work with the {magrittr} pipe operator.

This is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65534200/get-string-names-of-a-vector-of-functions-passed-into-another-function). But when I try it with the pipe, it fails.

```r
library(magrittr)

h <- function(func) {
  as.character(substitute(func))
}

# Works
h(eval)
#> [1] "eval"

# Doesn't work
eval() %>% h()
#> [1] "."

# Works
eval() %>% substitute() %>% as.character()
#> [1] "eval"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

What I'm expecting is:

```r
eval() %>% h()
#> [1] "eval"
```

Can this be done with a single function call and not a chain call like for the last example? I'm using {magrittr} version 2.0.1.

Comment: You can probably adapt the solution from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52066097/get-expression-that-evaluated-to-dot-in-function-called-by-magrittr-pipe) and convert the output to a string.

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect.